# Signed Java application blocked by Java security

Tags: java, security, certificate, jnlp

I have a java application signed with a valid globalsign certificate.
It must run on client computers on my website using a jnlp file in all-permissions mode.
I have checked:
jarsigner -verify myapp.jar

I get:  jar verified

But when the clients of my website execute it, they receive a message stating that Java security has blocked the application.

It is blocked even if one adds my site in the exceptions authorized by java.

I have searched, I do not understand... Few months ago it worked perfectly and I have not changed the jar file nor the jnlp file in the meantime ...

Comment: Have you checked if your certificate or any of the others in the chain has expired? Are you using the same Java version as your clients (major and minor)?

Comment: The certificate is valid until 2024.
I compiled the jar on a jdk8, several months ago. I tested on another jdk8 (different minor version and it blocks too).
If I had a certificate problem I should see it with jarsigner - verify,  isn't it?

Comment: Well, your users might trust different certs than you do, in particular if they are running other Java versions. Do you have any more specific errors?

Comment: No, sorry. I had the same problem on my own computer... but 2 weeks ago it worked... I've finally packaged a new signed jar file and it works. But I can't explain why! Thanks for your help